# strange result with shortest.path in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a small fully connected network obtained with:

```
m<-induced.subgraph(g, V(g)[village=="sar"])
```

here's a summary, 6 nodes and 30 links, a fully connected directed network:

```
IGRAPH DNWB 6 30 -- 
attr: id (v/n), name (v/c), village (v/c), religion (v/c), adoption.lag
(v/n), type (v/c), shape (v/c), size (v/n), color (v/c), dist (v/n),
dist.sar (v/n), weight (e/n)
```

when I run this, I got a surprising result:

```
>shortest.paths(m)
           A         B         C         D         E         F
A          0         3         3         3         3         3
B          3         0         3         3         3         3
C          3         3         0         3         3         3
D          3         3         3         0         3         3
E          3         3         3         3         0         3
F          3         3         3         3         3         0
```

The network is directed, with 6 nodes and 30 links so every node is linked to everyone else: shouldn't shortest paths values be 1? Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that links are weighted, and no matter if shortest.paths(g) is set by default to weights=NULL, I have:

```
> E(g)$weight<-1
> shortest.paths(g, V(g)[village=="rudakali"], to=V(g)[village=="rudakali"],weights=NULL)
            A          B         C          D           E          F
A           0          1         1          1           1          1
B           1          0         1          1           1          1
C           1          1         0          1           1          1
D           1          1         1          0           1          1
E           1          1         1          1           0          1
F           1          1         1          1           1          0
> E(g)$weight<-10
> shortest.paths(g, V(g)[village=="rudakali"], to=V(g)[village=="rudakali"],weights=NULL)
            A          B         C          D           E          F
A           0         10        10         10          10         10
B          10          0        10         10          10         10
C          10         10         0         10          10         10
D          10         10        10          0          10         10
E          10         10        10         10           0         10
F          10         10        10         10          10          0
```

EDIT after Gabor comment: to get rid of edge weights, the correct code would be, in my case:

```
shortest.paths(g, V(g)[village=="rudakali"], to=V(g)[village=="rudakali"],weights=NA)
```

Comment: `weights` Possibly a numeric vector giving edge weights. If this is NULL and the graph has a weight edge attribute, then the attribute is used. If this is NA then no weights are used (even if the graph has a weight attribute). http://igraph.org/r/doc/shortest.paths.html